# Flutter web showing blank white screen in Safari and mobile devices

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I am having a problem when trying to navigate through a deployed Flutter web app in Safari and Mobile Devices.
I have like 4 different screens in the app, 3 of them works fine, but when I redirect user to the principal screen, it just shows a blank white screen. This happens only in Safari and in Mobile Devices browsers (Chrome/Safari). When using Chrome and a desktop it works **as it should** (all screens shows normally).

When debugging with Chrome it works perfectly too.

[EDIT]
[Print console error with Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkqm.png)

I tried the following:

- Changing build type (--web renderer canvaskit / html --release)
- Changing channel from master to beta
- Updating Flutter and outdated packages
- Cleaning build a hundred times
- Debug with Safari but I don't think it's possible

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.